# OpenCMIS + Alfresco make file read-only

Tags: apache, cxf, alfresco, opencmis, apache-chemistry

I'm developing an Alfresco client which uses the OpenCMIS (Apache Chemistry) to upload files into Alfresco. I would like to know if there is a way to make a single file read-only for everyone.

Thanks,
Miretz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you'll need to use CMIS to alter the [Access Controls](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#Access_Control) on the node to change the permissions.

However...

From what you've described, I think your node will have "Inherit Permissions" turned on. This means that you can grant additional permissions with CMIS, via the Access Controls functionality, but you can't remove any permissions that come from the parent. [This Alfresco forum thread has more on it](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/disable-permission-inheritance-02202013-0351). Currently, I believe you'll need to use a tiny bit of Alfresco code (rule JS, Java, WebScript etc) to turn off the "Inherit Permissions" on your node. You can then use CMIS to grant people read access to it, without write (Consumer)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can't [disable inherited permissions](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-api/cant-remove-inherited-permissions-09112013-1522).

So what Can you do?

1. Get ALL the ACL's of the object you just uploaded/submitted to Alfresco. Set these to Read.
2. Create a rule/behaviour in the folder-tree where you save documents and disable the inherit permissions.